# Set-ExecutionPolicy using batch file + powershell script

Tags: windows-7, batch, powershell

I'm working on my dotfiles and I'm wanting to create a batch script that will do some initial setup for me when switching to a new computer, like using [psget](http://psget.net/) to install modules, etc... I'd also like it to go ahead and change my ExecutionPolicy to something usable.

I created a batch file that simply fires off a powershell script under the `Bypass` ExecutionPolicy:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass 
           -NoLogo -NoProfile -NoExit 
           -File .\set-policy.ps1
```

`set-policy.ps1` attempts to run powershell as administrator to change the ExecutionPolicy:

```
Start-Process powershell -verb runas 
  -ArgumentList "-No Exit -Command { Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted }"
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do that trick (output below). Not sure what the problem is.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

Any tips on how to use a batch file + powershell script to change execution policy?

Comment: Looks like there might be a problem with uac. Are you running this from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Yea, which is why when I launch powershell to change the execution policy I use `-verb runas` which will bring up the uac prompt and launch powershell as administrator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is how you are invoking the new PowerShell process; it seems to be executing commands before the PowerShell prompt is ready for it, so they just get printed to the console; I'm not sure why though. Anyways, here is the fix.

This is how your set-policy.ps1 file should look:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Force" -Verb RunAs
```

Or you can do the entire thing from the batch file in one line like so:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Force' -Verb RunAs}"
```

I provide a little more information around calling PowerShell scripts from batch files and why you would want to do it [on my blog post here](http://blog.danskingdom.com/allow-others-to-run-your-powershell-scripts-from-a-batch-file-they-will-love-you-for-it/).

Comment: +1 That blog post is pure Gold! Unfortunate though, that dealing with PowerShell is made this difficult. Someone must have actually Planned it?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for me to do this was to edit the registry. So now my batch file simply contains:

```
regedit.exe /S EnableScripts.reg
```

Running that will automatically prompt the user for permission/credentials as necessary. My `EnableScripts.reg` file just contains the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell]
"Path"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
"ExecutionPolicy"="RemoteSigned"
```

The registry setting above was sufficient except for when running the x86 PowerShell (on my 64 bit machine). That required additionally setting the registry keys below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell]
"Path"="C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
"ExecutionPolicy"="RemoteSigned"
```